# ACRA Insert report into my server's database

Tags: php, android, mysql, acra

I successfully configured ACRA to send my caught exceptions to my server, the problem is I can't insert the report into the database:

```
@AcraCore(buildConfigClass = BuildConfig.class)
@AcraHttpSender(uri = "http://www.myserver.com/crashreports/addreport.php",
        httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST)

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

I know it sends somethings because I see an empty entry in my `phpMyAdmin`, but I can't get the report inside the database:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "db");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$report = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO VoiceRemoteCrash (report) VALUES ('$report')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I've searched docs, but didn't find much info, and my `PHP` knowledge is somewhat basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_REQUEST['']` will returns `NULL` and will throw an *"undefined index"* notice.

You could get your report from POST raw data using `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

I suggest you to have a look to : [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and use parameterized queries.

Comment: Should I add it this way? $report = file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 Replace `$_REQUEST['']` by `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This line references a nonsense variable:

```
$report = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['']);
```

You want something like:

```
$report = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['form_variable_name']);
```

But you shouldn't even do that, because the `real_escape_string()` functions can not be relied on to prevent SQL injection. Instead, you should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) driver. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: I know that, it just I don't know the 'form_variable_name' that ACRA sends, and I looked everywhere, didn't find it

Comment: Just `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

Comment: The problem is that the app sends the report via http request, there is no way to var_dump